# Add Programmatically added textField's text to sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have sqlite implemented in my xcode project. It gets its data from a `UITextField`. There is a `texField` that gets added programmatically everytime the user clicks a `button`. I will be recreating the 'same' `textField`. (Kind of.) How can I get the `textField's` data to the sqlie file?

**`SQLite` Created in Terminal**

```
CREATE TABLE myDB(myDBID integer primary key, first text, second text);
```

**`Objective C`**

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into myDB values(null, '%@', '%@')", self.textView1.text, self.textView2.text];
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

//IBAction:
UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:text];
```

How can I add the programmatically added `textField's` text to the `sqlite` database?

**Update**

Basically textFields get added programmatically with an ibaction. What I'm trying to do, is get the textFields text and add it to sqlite. I can't just add it like so:

```
@"insert into myDB values(null, '%@', '%@')", self.textView1.text, self.textView2.text];
```

because I don't know how many textFields there will be, and I therefore don't know how many fields I should create in sqlite. (Fields meaning - first text, second text

Comment: ??  You retrieve the data from the text field and do an INSERT or UPDATE into the DB.  What's the question??

Comment: I don't know how many textFields there will be, so what do I do about the sqlite file? There is 2 text inputs in the sqlite file (`first text, second text`).

Comment: It seems to me that question has nothing to do with text fields.  We haven't a clue what you're doing with the data you put into the SQLite file, so we can't advise you on how to insert it.

Comment: Basically textFields get added programmatically with an ibaction. What I'm trying to do, is get the textFields text and add it to sqlite. I can't just add it like so: `@"insert into myDB values(null, '%@', '%@')", self.textView1.text, self.textView2.text];` 1 cuz I don't know how many textFields there will be, and I therefore don't know how many fields I should do in sqlite. (Fields meaning - first text, second text

Comment: And, once again, we have no idea what you're doing with those values, so we cannot help you come up with a workable design.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your asking, I'm gonna be storing it in a field in sqlite

Comment: I've dealt with you before, so I know it's useless to continue.  You will never actually tell us how you're using the data.  Goodbye.

Comment: I'm gonna be showing it in a UILabel. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I don't think this is anything close to best practice, I believe what you will have to do is iterate over all your `UITextField`s and adjust your query throughout the loop, unless you want to split it up into multiple queries. As long as you don't have any extraneous `UITextField`s this should work. The order should be earliest added -> latest though I'm not positive so I would test it.

```
NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"insert into myDB values(null"];

for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass: NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")]) {
        UITextField *temp = subview;
        [query appendFormat:@", '%@'", temp.text];
    }
}
[query appendString:@")"];
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
```

**Edit**

As far as updating your SQLite table, there is no way to change the number of columns dynamically. So you can either store multiple values in a single field using a comma-delimited string or create a lot of column and limit the number of text fields to that maximum.

Comment: I don't know how many textFields there will be, so what do I do about the sqlite file? There is 2 text inputs in the sqlite file (`first text, second text`).

Comment: you could do **ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype** to match the number of textfields, but I wouldn't. I would set an upper maximum for the number of text fields they can have and have your SQL table have space for all of them so its consistent.

Comment: @Chase - You certainly shouldn't attempt to dynamically alter the table (even if you could, which you can't).  The problem needs to be thought through, before a database design is put in place.

Comment: @Hot Licks yeah I figured. What about the code that cycles through all the textfields in the view. Would that work assuming the DB Table has space for all the values?

Comment: It's foolish to even speculate, give that the OP has not given us a clue as to how the data will be used.

Comment: @Chase Is there another way of doing it? (Without dynamically altering the table?

Comment: @Mike See my edit. Honestly this is not the best DB design and I would take Hot's advice and rethink your db structure, but just to get this one working you can use a delimiter that you know the user won't type in and store all the values in a single field and when you parse it for your label use **NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];** it doesn't have to be a comma.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! What do you mean rethink the db structure, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @Mike I would think of a way to do so the text fields add themselves as rows to the DB (which are designed to be dynamically added and removed) but I'm not sure what you're doing with your data. You'll most likely have to take what is now one table and make it multiple tables that incorporates a one-to-many relationship for these values. I'd read up on table relationships but in the long run your database will be much more flexible.